Contradictory requirements for Baire Space applied to N?
Baire spaces are defined as metric space where every countable intersection of open dense sets is also dense, or equivalently, every countable union of closed sets with empty interior has empty interior.
These two definitions seem to contradict when applied to $\mathbb{N}$:

The only open dense set in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is $\mathbb{N}$ itself, so it must be closed under countable intersection.
Each singleton has empty interior and is closed (and open), but their union is $\mathbb{N}$, which is dense.

I expect there's some other requirement for something to be a Baire space that I'm missing...

The two definitions don't contradict.
The error lies in the statement "each singleton has empty interior." In fact, you acknowledge that each singleton is open right after, so since the interior of a subspace is the largest open subspace contained within, it follows that the interior of a singleton is itself. Thus, the only closed set with empty interior is the empty set and the second condition is vacuously fulfilled.

Ah, dang.  Thank you.
